# Rspec Failure/Error matching a string value

Tags: rspec

I am trying to figure out why my rspec test fails when matching a string value.  Other tests doing similar matching are successful.

I get the following failed result:

> 1) Class #method should get the string
>
> > ```
> > Failure/Error: class.method.should == "LD 513"
> >  expected: "LD 513"
> >  got: "LD 513" (using ==)
> > ```

If I output the result to the screen, I see this which shows the value of the variable and the variable type so my assumption is that everything should pass.

> variable: "LD 513" -- String

Any idea why this test fails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.  It was a character encoding issue.  Essentially a hidden character was in between the letters and numbers.  Once I normalized the string, the test passed.